# How to wrap unwrapped strings in html tag?

Tags: javascript, html

```
// From
var first = 'Text here <code>var first = "first";</code> Another text 
<code>var second = "second";</code>'
// To 
var second =  '<p>Text here</p> <code>var first = "first";</code> 
<p>Another text</p> <code>var second = "second";</code>'
```

I receive a string like "From", I need to parse it to second example, is there way to do this?

Comment: You'll have to parse your string as a DOM object and then lex it. But there's a lot to do. Whatever you do don't be teased by the idea of regexes

Comment: From where you receive it? Manipulate HTML, if possible, rather than relying on regex, although, regex solutions are possible, too...

Comment: From the server. I'm just trying to make something like this: I type a <code>code here...</code> inside a textarea + some regular text(outside of <code> tag) in the end I receive a string, like in a first example, than I need to display it in html somehow, that's it, if I wrap this regular text in <p> or <span> I can display it in a correct order through map method + DOMparser. If there's a better way to do this, let me know pls. P.S. sorry for bad English, still learning

Comment: @ivemm Are you using jQuery? I know it's the most annoying thing for people to ask, but it will allow for a much shorter and simpler answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an element, put that string into the element and then iterate the child nodes and replace text nodes with new `<p>` that contains associated text. Then finally get the resultant html

```js
// From
var first = `Text here <code>var first = "first";</code> Another text 
<code>var second = "second";</code>`


var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = first;

var nodes = div.childNodes;

for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
  if (nodes[i].nodeType == 3) {
    var p = document.createElement('p');
    p.textContent = nodes[i].textContent;
    div.replaceChild(p, nodes[i])
  }
}

let res = div.innerHTML;

console.log(res)
```